# Web audio oscillator is clicking in Firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create a simple metronome using the web audio oscillator, so that no external audio files are needed. I'm creating the sound of the metronome by ramping the volume of the oscillator up and down very quickly (since you can't use start() and stop() more than once), and then repeating that function at a set interval. It ends up sounding like a nice little wood block.

The code below works/sounds great in Chrome, Safari and Opera. But in Firefox, there's a nasty intermittent "click" when the volume ramps up. I've tried changing the attack/release times to get rid of the click, but they have to be really, really long before it consistently disappears. So long, in fact, that the oscillator just sounds like a sustained note.

```
var audio = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var tick = audio.createOscillator();
var tickVol = audio.createGain();

tick.type = 'sine'; 
tick.frequency.value = 1000;
tickVol.gain.value = 0; //setting the volume to 0 before I connect everything
tick.connect(tickVol);
tickVol.connect(audio.destination);
tick.start(0);

var metronome = {
    start: function repeat() {
        now = audio.currentTime;

        //Make sure volume is 0 and that no events are changing it
        tickVol.gain.cancelScheduledValues(now);
        tickVol.gain.setValueAtTime(0, now);

        //Play the osc with a super fast attack and release so it sounds like a click
        tickVol.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, now + .001);
        tickVol.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, now + .001 + .01);

        //Repeat this function every half second
        click = setTimeout(repeat, 500);
    },
    stop: function() {
        if(typeof click !== 'undefined') {
            clearTimeout(click);
            tickVol.gain.value = 0;
        }
    }
}

$("#start").click(function(){
  metronome.start();
});

$("#stop").click(function(){
  metronome.stop();
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/schwenky/pen/yeKOYR)

Is there any way to get FF to sound like the other 3 browsers?

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the exact same problem in latest Opera and found the problem to be the individual sounds 'decimal time length'.

I wrote a morse code translator, and like yours, it's just a series of simple short sounds/beeps created via createOscillator.

With morse code you have a speed count (words per minute) based on a 5 letter long word like codex or paris.

To get 20 or 30 paris' per minute to finish exactly on the minute, I had to use a sound time length of, for example, 0.61. In Opera, this caused the 'end of sound click'. On changing this to 0.6 and the click disappeared across all browsers - except Firefox.

I've tried freq = 0 and gain = 0 between sounds but still get the click at the end in FF and I don't know enough about Web Audio to try anything else.

On another note, I noticed you're using a loop and timeout to get to the next tick. Have you tried an 'Oscillator onended function' instead? I've used it with a simple counter increment and variable length blank sound/note. Go to the very end of my JS if you want to have a look.

**UPDATE - I've been fiddling about with setValueAtTime() and linearRampToValueAtTime() and appeared to have cracked the click problem. Scroll to bottom of script to see example. **

```js
(function(){

/* Morse Code Generator & Translator - Kurt Grigg 2003 (Updated for sound and CSS3) */

var d = document;
d.write('<div class="Mcontainer">'
+'<div class="Mtitle">Morse Code Generator Translator</div>'
+'<textarea id="txt_in" class="Mtxtarea"></textarea>'
+'<div class="Mtxtareatitle">Input</div>'
+'<textarea id="txt_out" class="Mtxtarea" style="top: 131px;"></textarea>'
+'<div class="Mtxtareatitle" style="top: 172px;">Output</div>'
+'<div class="Mbuttonwrap">'
+'<input type="button" class="Mbuttons" id="how" value="!">'
+'<input type="button" class="Mbuttons" id="tra" value="translate">'
+'<input type="button" class="Mbuttons" id="ply" value="play">'
+'<input type="button" class="Mbuttons" id="pau" value="pause">'
+'<input type="button" class="Mbuttons" id="res" value="reset"></div>'
+'<select id="select" class="Mselect">' 
+'<option value=0.07 selected="selected">15 wpm</option>'
+'<option value=0.05>20 wpm</option>'
+'<option value=0.03>30 wpm</option>'
+'</select>'
+'<div class="sliderWrap">volume <input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" value="0.05"/></div>'
+'<div class="Mchckboxwrap">'
+'<span style="text-align: right;">separator <input type="checkbox" id="slash" class="Mchckbox"></span>'
+'</div>'
+'<div id="about" class="Minfo">'
+'<b>Input morse</b><br>'
+'<ul><li>Enter morse into input box using full stop (period) and minus sign (hyphen)</li>'
+'<li>Morse letters must be separated by 1 space</li>'
+'<li>Morse words must be separated by 3 or more spaces</li>'
+'<li>You can use / to separate morse words. There must be at least 1 space before and after each separator used</li>'
+'</ul>'
+'<b>Input text</b><br>'
+'<ul class="Mul"><li>Enter text into input box</li>'
+'<li>Characters that cannot be translated will be ignored</li>'
+'<li>If morse and text is entered, the converter will assume morse mode</li></ul>'
+'<input type="button" value="close" id="clo" class="Mbuttons">'
+'</div><div id="mdl" class="modal"><div id="bdy"><div id="modalMsg">A MSG</div><input type="button" value="close" id="cls" class="Mbuttons"></div></div></div>');

var ftmp = d.getElementById('mdl');
var del;

d.getElementById('tra').addEventListener("click", function(){convertToAndFromMorse(txtIn.value);},false);
d.getElementById('ply').addEventListener("click", function(){CancelIfPlaying();},false);
d.getElementById('pau').addEventListener("click", function(){stp();},false);
d.getElementById('res').addEventListener("click", function(){Rst();txtIn.value = '';txtOt.value = '';},false);


d.getElementById('how').addEventListener("click", function(){msgSelect();},false);
d.getElementById('clo').addEventListener("click", function(){fadeOut();},false);

d.getElementById('cls').addEventListener("click", function(){fadeOut();},false);
d.getElementById('bdy').addEventListener("click", function(){errorSelect();},false);

var wpm = d.getElementById('select');
wpm.addEventListener("click", function(){wpMin()},false);

var inc = 0;
var playing = false; 
var txtIn = d.getElementById('txt_in');
var txtOt = d.getElementById('txt_out');
var paused = false;
var allowed = ['-','.',' '];
var aud;
var tmp = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)?true:false;
if (tmp) {
    aud = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
}
var incr = 0;
var speed = parseFloat(wpm.options[wpm.selectedIndex].value);
var char = [];
var alphabet = [["A",".-"],["B","-..."],["C","-.-."],["D","-.."],["E","."],["F","..-."],["G","--."],["H","...."],["I",".."],["J",".---"],
    ["K","-.-"],["L",".-.."],["M","--"],["N","-."],["O","---"],["P",".--."],["Q","--.-"],["R",".-."],["S","..."],["T","-"],["U","..-"],
    ["V","...-"],["W",".--"],["X","-..-"],["Y","-.--"],["Z","--.."],["1",".----"],["2","..---"],["3","...--"],["4","....-"],["5","....."],
    ["6","-...."],["7","--..."],["8","---.."],["9","----."],["0","-----"],[".",".-.-.-"],[",","--..--"],["?","..--.."],["'",".----."],["!","-.-.--"],
    ["/","-..-."],[":","---..."],[";","-.-.-."],["=","-...-"],["-","-....-"],["_","..--.-"],["\"",".-..-."],["@",".--.-."],["(","-.--.-"],[" ",""]];

function errorSelect() {
    txtIn.focus();
}

function modalSwap(msg) {
    d.getElementById('modalMsg').innerHTML = msg;
}

function msgSelect() {
    ftmp = d.getElementById('about');
    fadeIn(); 
}

function fadeIn() {
    ftmp.removeEventListener("transitionend", freset);
    ftmp.style.display = "block";
    del = setTimeout(doFadeIn,100);
}

function doFadeIn() {
    clearTimeout(del);
    ftmp.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear";
    ftmp.style.opacity = "1";
}

function fadeOut() {
    ftmp.style.transition = "opacity 0.8s linear";
    ftmp.style.opacity = "0";
    ftmp.addEventListener("transitionend",freset , false);
}

function freset() {
    ftmp.style.display = "none";
    ftmp.style.transition = "";
    ftmp = d.getElementById('mdl');
}

function stp() {
    paused = true;
}

function wpMin() {
    speed = parseFloat(wpm.options[wpm.selectedIndex].value);
}

function Rst(){ 
    char = [];
    inc = 0;
    playing = false;
    paused = false;
}

function CancelIfPlaying(){
    if (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext) {paused = false;
        if (!playing) { 
            IsReadyToHear();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        modalSwap("<p>Your browser doesn't support Web Audio API</p>");
        fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
}

function IsReadyToHear(x){
    if (txtIn.value == "" || /^\s+$/.test(txtIn.value)) {
        modalSwap('<p>Nothing to play, enter morse or text first</p>');
        fadeIn();
        txtIn.value = '';
        return false;
    }
    else if (char.length < 1 && (x != "" || !/^\s+$/.test(txtIn.value)) && txtIn.value.length > 0) {
        modalSwap('<p>Click Translate button first . . .</p>');
        fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        playMorse();
    }
}

function convertToAndFromMorse(x){
    var swap = [];
    var outPut = "";
    x = x.toUpperCase();

    /* Is input empty or all whitespace? */
    if (x == '' || /^\s+$/.test(x)) {
        modalSwap("<p>Nothing to translate, enter morse or text</p>");
        fadeIn();
        txtIn.value = '';
        return false;
    }

    /* Remove front & end whitespace */
    x = x.replace(/\s+$|^\s*/gi, ''); 
    txtIn.value = x;
    txtOt.value = "";

    var isMorse = (/(\.|\-)\.|(\.|\-)\-/i.test(x));// Good enough.

    if (!isMorse){
        for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
            swap[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                swap[i][j] = alphabet[i][j].replace(/\-/gi, '\\-');
            }
        }
    }

    var swtch1 = (isMorse) ? allowed : swap;
    var tst = new RegExp( '[^' + swtch1.join('') + ']', 'g' ); 
    var swtch2 = (isMorse)?' ':'';
    x = x.replace( tst, swtch2);  //remove unwanted chars.
    x = x.split(swtch2); 

    if (isMorse) {
        var tidy = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            if ((x[i] != '') || x[i+1] == '' && x[i+2] != '') {
                tidy.push(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    var swtch3 = (isMorse) ? tidy : x;

    for (var j = 0; j < swtch3.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
            if (isMorse) {
                if (tidy[j] == alphabet[i][1]) {
                    outPut += alphabet[i][0];
                } 
            } 
            else {
                if (x[j] == alphabet[i][0]) {
                    outPut += alphabet[i][1] + ((j < x.length-1)?"  ":"");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isMorse) {
        var wordDivide = (d.getElementById('slash').checked)?"  /  ":"     ";
        outPut = outPut.replace(/\s{3,}/gi, wordDivide);
    }

    if (outPut.length < 1) {
        alert('Enter valid text or morse...');
        txtIn.value = '';
    }
    else {
        txtOt.value = outPut;
    }

    var justMorse = (!isMorse) ? outPut : tidy;

    FormatForSound(justMorse);
}

function FormatForSound(s){
    var n = [];
    var b = '';
    if (typeof s == 'object') {
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
            var f = (i == s.length-1)?'':'  ';
            var t = b += (s[i] + f);
        }
    }
    var c = (typeof s == 'object')? t : s;
    c = c.replace(/\//gi, '');
    c = c.replace(/\s{1,3}/gi, '4');
    c = c.replace(/\./gi, '03');
    c = c.replace(/\-/gi, '13');  
    c = c.split('');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        n.push(c[i]);
    }
    char = n;
}

function vlm() {
    return document.getElementById('volume').value;
}

function playMorse() {

    if (paused){ 
        playing = false;
        return false;
    }

    playing = true;
    if (incr >= char.length) {
        incr = 0;
        playing = false;
        paused = false;
        return false;
    }
    
    var c = char[incr];
    var freq = 550;
    var volume = (c < 2) ? vlm() : 0 ;
    var flen = (c == 0 || c == 3) ? speed : speed * 3;

    var osc = aud.createOscillator();
    osc.type = 'sine'; 
    osc.frequency.value = freq;

    var oscGain = aud.createGain();
    oscGain.gain.value = volume;
    osc.connect(oscGain);
    oscGain.connect(aud.destination);

    var now = aud.currentTime;

    osc.start(now);

        /*
        Sharp volume fade to stop harsh clicks if wave is stopped 
        at a point other than the (natural zero crossing point) 
        */
        oscGain.gain.setValueAtTime(volume, now + (flen*0.8));
        oscGain.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0.0, now + (flen*0.9999));
    
    
    osc.stop(now + flen);

    osc.onended = function() {
        incr++;
        playMorse();
    }
}      
})();
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;  
}





.Mcontainer {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 382px;
height: 302px;
border: 1px solid #000;
border-radius: 6px;
text-align: center;
font: bold 11px sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(203,243,65);
box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.Mtitle {
-webkit-user-select: none;   
-moz-user-select: none;   
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 380px;
height: 20px;
margin: auto;
left: 0; right: 0;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
color:  #666;
}
.Mtxtareatitle {
-webkit-user-select: none;   
-moz-user-select: none; 
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: -36px;
height: 22px;
width: 106px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 22px;
text-align: center;
color: #555;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.Mtxtarea {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 18px;
margin: auto;
left: 0; right: 0;
height: 98px;
width: 344px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
border-radius: 6px;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-left: 24px;
resize: none;
background-color: #fffff0;
font: bold 10px courier;
color: #555;
text-transform: uppercase;
overflow: auto;
outline: 0;    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.Minfo {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: -6px; left:-6px;
padding: 6px;
height: auto;
width:  370px;
text-align: left;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
border-radius: 6px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background-color: rgb(203,243,65);
font: 11px sans-serif;
color: #555;
opacity: 0;
}
.Mbuttonwrap {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 245px;
margin: auto;
left: 0; right: 0;
height: 26px;
width: 100%;
}
.Mbuttons {
display: inline-block;
width: 69px;
height: 22px;
border: none;
margin: 0px 3.1px 0px 3.1px;
background-color: transparent;
font: bold 11px sans-serif;
color: #555;
border-radius: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
outline: 0;
}
.Mbuttons:hover {
background-color:  rgb(213,253,75);
}
.Mbuttons:active {
position: relative;
top: 1px;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.Mchckboxwrap {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 274px;
left: 289px;
width: 87px;
height: 21px;
line-height: 22px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
color: #555;
background: #fff;
-webkit-user-select: none;   
-moz-user-select: none;   
}
.Mselect {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 274px;
left: 6px;
width: 88px;
height: 22px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
padding-left: 5%;
background: #fff;
font: bold 11px sans-serif;
color: #555;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
outline: 0;
}
::selection {
color: #fff;
background: #555;
}
.Mchckbox {
margin-top: 1px;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
outline: 0;
}
.modal {
display: none;
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-moz-user-select: none;
opacity: 0;
text-align: center;
}
.modal > div {   
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 70px;
margin: 10% auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
border-radius:6px;
background-color: rgb(203,243,65);
font: bold 11px sans-serif;
color: #555;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
text-align: center;
}
.sliderWrap {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 274px;
margin:auto;padding: 0;
left: 0; right: 0;
width: 184px;
height: 21px;
border: 0.5px solid #000;
background: #fff;
font: bold 11px sans-serif;
color: #555;
line-height: 21px;
text-align: center;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
outline: 0;
}
input[type=range] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;padding: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
width: 100%;
height: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
background: #666;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border: none;
height: 10px;
width: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-appearance: none;
margin-top: -3px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
background: #666;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
width: 100%;
height: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
background: #666;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
height: 10px;
width: 20px;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #ffffff;
cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
height: 10px;
width: 20px;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
width: 100%;
height: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
background: transparent;
border: 5px solid transparent;
color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
background: #666;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
background: #666;
}
::-ms-tooltip {
display: none;
}
select::-ms-expand {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, what I'm observing is when the decimal time gets below .05s, FF starts to get buggy. Unfortunately, I need keep it small in order to simulate the "clicking" sound of a metronome, so I don't have much leeway. I did, however, submit a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248731) to Mozilla.

Comment: I've done a bit of reading on this and unfortunately it is not a bug! Turns out the click sound happens because we're abruptly cutting the sound wave at a point other than the "natural zero crossing". Oh well, back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to get Firefox to fix the issue (if indeed it is a Firefox bug with automations).  Having said that, you could probably make all the browsers be consistent by using an AudioBufferSource node that has a precomputed click waveform that you want.  Just generate a sine wave, ramp it up and down as you want (manually) and play that back at regular intervals.

Not great, but it should be cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, and sorry I'm just now responding. I [submitted a bug to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248731), and [created a version of this](http://codepen.io/schwenky/pen/dGjMvE?editors=0010) using an audio buffer per your suggestion, but the results have even less consistent audio across browsers. I'm going to keep tinkering with an oscillator only solution, and see if Mozilla truly considers the behavior to be a bug.

Comment: That is weird and makes even less sense to me.  Note also that I know that FF has some issues with its parameter automations.  Compare what Chrome does and FF does with http://googlechrome.github.io/web-audio-samples/samples/audio/timeline.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this issue is not specific to Firefox, although looking at your code, I'm unsure why it doesn't happen in other browsers.

The problem is that the moment you schedule a *rampToValueAtTime to an audible source when that source is not currently interpolating between two ramp points, the "clicking" sound occurrs, possibly due to how the underlying implementation will immediately start taking the new ramp point into consideration, even if it's scheduled to happen the future.

The clicking sound will also be heard if you schedule a new ramp point between two points between which interpolation is occurring.

What I came up with as a workaround solution is either using an alternative approach to gradually changing AudioParam values, [setTargetAtTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/setTargetAtTime), or setting the `value` property of the AudioParam to the first ramp point value. Not setValueAtTime, but assigning to the value property itself, before anything audible happens on the given branch.

---

### setTargetAtTime

You'll be needing neither cancelScheduledValues nor setValueAtTime, just two calls to setTargetAtTime, which is just a setValueAtTime with an exponential interpolation with a specified length.

```
var metronome = {
    start: function repeat() {
        now = audio.currentTime;

        //Play the osc with a super fast attack and release so it sounds like a click
        tickVol.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, now, 0.01);
        tickVol.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, now + 0.01, 0.01);

        //Repeat this function every half second
        click = setTimeout(repeat, 500);
    }
}
```

[Live demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ssc6ho/)

Comment: Thanks John, your description of the *rampToValueAtTime behavior makes perfect sense! Unfortunately, your fiddle doesn't produce any sound for me in FF (although it works great in Chrome). If I increase the time (on line 18 of the JS pane) from .005 to .2, it starts to play consistently in FF, but as in my first example, the clicking is still pretty pronounced. Are you seeing/hearing the same behavior on your end?

Also, I tried setting the initial `value` of the gain node to match the first ramp point value, but still got the same results.

Comment: Directly setting the value property will soon (if not already) not work.  In Chrome, setting the value property would cause smoothing.  However, the spec is being changed so that it will behave as if you did a setValueAtTime(value, now).  If you want or need smoothing you need to do setTargetAtTime().